# Greek small rho with dasia (and also psili): Problem with accent and LGR encoding

Tags: greek

The following minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,QX,T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont
ὉῥὙ ἠἈἐ Ὤἔ
\end{document}
```

sets all accents perfect.

[image: Computer Modern Greek accents]

However, if I use a different font like \usepackage{MinionPro}, the dasia above the rho is at a wrong height. If I use an own font (the horizontal kerning is not done yet), the same problem arises:

[image: Miama Greek accents]

This is strange, because the LGR encoding stores a correct "rho with dasia" at its 251st code slot.

How can one fix this? Do I have to add a kind of vertical kerning to my font or is this an undiscovered problem of lgrenc.def which does not appear for Computer Modern because all the accents are at the same height anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my system LGR maps `\accdasia r` to glyph 251 but not `ῥ` which is defined as `\accdasia \textrho` and ends as "rho + accent" in the pdf. I get the real glyph only if I add a suitable mapping:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,QX,T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareTextComposite{\accdasia}{LGR}{\textrho}{251}
\begin{document}
\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont
\accdasia r
\accdasia \textrho
ῥ
\end{document}
```

It looks like an oversight to me (but my knowledge of greek is non-existing) so I suggest a bug report. I couldn't test if this solves your problem with MinionPro as I don't have it installed here.

Comment: After your answer and an additional look at lgrenc.def I am quite sure that this is an oversight, as \DeclareTextComposite{\accdasia}{LGR}{r}{251} appears twice and it should obviously be \DeclareTextComposite{\accdasia}{LGR}{\textrho}{251} at the second appearing (as you suggested). I will try to report it.

Comment: Günter Milde has fixed the bug and has uploaded it on CTAN (e.g. ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/language/greek/greek-fontenc/lgrenc.def)

Answer (score 0):

Running your document with `xelatex` and Minion Pro looks ok:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\begin{document}
ὉῥὙ ἠἈἐ Ὤἔ \itshape ὉῥὙ ἠἈἐ Ὤἔ
\end{document}
```

[image]